# Access fields in Django intermediate model of Groups

Tags: python, django, model, many-to-many

I'm creating a model of Group with Person and Membership, all like described in Django docs.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):              
        return self.name


class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):              
        return self.name


class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    leader = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

I'm just making this all in views, becouse i want to make this "creating groups" as a function in my web app.

views.py:

```
@login_required
def groups(request):
user = request.user

if request.method == "POST":
    form = GroupForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        formm = form.save(commit=False)

        g = Group.objects.create(name = formm.name)
        p = Person.objects.create(name=request.user)
        m = Membership.objects.create(person=p, group=g, leader=True)



        gr = Group.objects.all()
        per = Person.objects.all()
        mem = Membership.objects.all()
        context = {
        'gr': gr,
        'per':per,
        'mem':mem,
        'form': form,
        }
        return render(request, 'groups.html', context )

else:

    gr = Group.objects.all()
    per = Person.objects.all()
    mem = Membership.objects.all()
    form = GroupForm()

    context = {
        'gr': gr,
        'per':per,
        'mem':mem,
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'groups.html', context)
```

groups.html:

```
{% block profile %}
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h4>Create a new group here:</h4>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Go!</button>
    </form>
  </div>


        {% for m in mem %}
        <div class="jumbotron">
          <br>
            <p><b>Name of group:</b> {{ m.group }} </p> 
            <p><b>Member:</b> {{ m.person }} </p>
          <br>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}



{% endblock %}
```

The problem is when I want to use

```
Membership.objects.filter(person=request.user)
```

and get error:

```
ValueError at /groups/
Cannot query "damian": Must be "Person" instance.
```

where damian is the name of the `request.user`

I just want to filter this to show in template only chosen memberships, groups etc...

Any one know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us the full stacktrace please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this,

```
Membership.objects.filter(person__name=request.user)
```

or

```
p = Person.objects.get(name=request.user)
Membership.objects.filter(person=p)
```

You must pass a `Person` class instance to `person` argument in `Membership` filter query.

Comment: Cool, it works! Thank you very much! :) I will remember this rule. But i wonder wheter it is a rule from clear python or django? I'm beginner and still learingn :)

Comment: And... what's more interesting, i have this code for example: {% for g in gr %} <p><b>Name:</b> {{ g.name }} {{g.members}}</p> 
            {% endfor %}
And wonder, why {{g.name}} is displaying properly, but when i want to see displaying results from {{g.members}} it's like : 'proj.Person.None'.
Idk why, it's showing me only the way...

Comment: is `members` a property in Group model class? You must only access the class properties through dot operator. It's better if you add your `Group` Model class code.

Comment: What do you mean? i have this property as u can see in my code. But when i create Group object, i only set a name, without any others. Could you show me what you mean? This should help